# Using libnfc with golang

Tags: c, dll, go, cgo, lib-nfc

I successfully compiled libnfc written in C under Windows.
After compilation I get 3 files: libnfc.dll, libnfc.dll.a, libnfc.lib.
I want to call functions of this library in my Go application.
My test program

```
package main
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I .
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L . -lnfc
#include <nfc/nfc.h>
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
  res:= C.nfc_version() 
  fmt.Printf(C.GoString(res))
}
```

nfc_version - name of function available in library.
I put libnfc.lib file in directory with go source and also copy folder nfc with header files.
(If I put libnfc.dll or libnfc.dll.a instead of libnfc.lib - I get error message library not found.)
Then I run

```
go build
```

Go successfully compiled program, but when I try to start it I get error: "This application has failed to start because (null).DLL was not found."
How to properly use library with golang application?

Comment: I wrote Go bindings for the libnfc a while ago. Maybe you can use them.

Comment: Yes I also tried to use this bindings.  
Install it by go get and  write test program

    package main
    import "github.com/fuzxxl/nfc"
    import "fmt"

    func main() {
    res:= nfc.Version()
    fmt.Printf(res)
    }

But I couldn't managed to build it.

Could you describe some steps in order to use your library?

Comment: well, where did it fail? Do you have the libnfc installed and set up so the Go compiler finds it? Have you ever worked with DLLs before?

Comment: Now I create env variable LIBRARY_PATH and point it to libnfc.lib file
So Go compiler find it and successfully build app, but I get same error when try to start it "This application has failed to start because (null).DLL was not found."

Comment: When I try to register libnfc.dll by 
`regsvr32.exe libnfc.dll` 
I get error: 
DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Comment: It seems that error occurs due to libnfc.dll compiled as 32bit dll.
Go compiler couldn't use 32bit library with 64bit application. 
I tried to make 32bit Go app using "Set GOARCH=386" but pakages with cgo don't support this option.
So the only option is to try to compile libnfc as 64bit library under Windows. 
Any ideas how to do that? 
I use this tutorial in order to compile it under Windows
http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/libnfc/libnfc.html